# What does the fourth number in the Linux kernel version of my Android phone means?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I have purchased SAMSUNG Galaxy Note3, if I go in Settings -> About device, there is a field named as Kernel version and it say

Kernel version = 3.4.0-1628120

What does the numbers after dash (-) mean? or please explain the kernel version system.

Comment: It is the build number. Why it is important?

Comment: I wrote a script that reads /proc/stat after every second for 2 minutes. I noticed the 4th field (IdleTime) was decreasing sometimes and it seems like a bug in the kernel, I have been searching if that is the case because it does not make sense as this filed must increase or stay constant based on the CPU load, I do not have much knowledge of the Kernel but just wanted to know why is it so and if its a bug where to find it for this version of the Kernel.
[/proc/stat] http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm

Answer (score 2):

The build number.
[This is the wiki about the versioning of the kernel.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Version_numbering)

Usually a build number gets bumped [everytime the code gets compiled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build), thats why its so high.